# Any system independent path for 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter'?

Tags: protractor

In my conf.js file, the path to 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter' mentioned is:

**C:/Users/swati.m.khandelwal/node_modules/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter**

Now, I want the conf.js file to run in some other system which has some other username. So, is there any way with the help of which my conf.js file runs independently without making any path changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed `protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` globally or locally? If its local to your project, then you dont have to give the complete path..

Comment: @GirishSortur
I have installed it globally.